# How can i choose uppercase words with regexp

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Hi i want a regular expression match all words with first letter uppercase.
But there is this greedy problem.

If i use `\<[[:upper:]].*\>` It will start matching at word starting with uppercase letter, but will end at the end of a last word on a line (with Grep)

So i tried `\<[[:upper:]][^\>]*\>` "Start of a word, any Uppercase letter, any count of any character which is not end of a word and then end of a word"

So why is the result still same?

Comment: perhaps `[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+` gets you closer? Unless `A` counts, in which case turn the + to a *

Comment: The results are the same for `grep` because `grep` doesn't need to see the subtle difference between the two expressions. In the first expression `.*` matches anything until the _last_ `>`. In the second expression `[^\>]*` matches anything until the first occurence of `>`. In both cases `grep` returns a match and doesn't care whether it's matching the first or last occurence of `>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
grep -E -o '[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+' file
```